# Calculate Month Difference in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

BigQuery does not allow you to select the daypart MONTH in DATEDIFF.

Is there any other way to do this in BigQuery.

I can get days difference using the following but not months.

```
SELECT 
  OrderID,
  OrderDate,
  STRING( YEAR ( OrderDate )) + '-' + STRING(MONTH ( OrderDate )) as order_month, 
  UserID,
  FirstOrderDate
DATEDIFF( OrderDate, FirstOrderDate) as date_diff,
FROM [orders.orders] 
WHERE FirstOrderDate > DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'YEAR')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
(12 * YEAR(t2) + MONTH(t2)) - (12 * YEAR(t1) + MONTH(t1))
    + IF (DAY(t2) >= DAY(t1), 0, -1)
```

Running it over a couple of examples, it looks like what you'd want:

```
SELECT 
(12 * YEAR(t2) + MONTH(t2)) - (12 * YEAR(t1) + MONTH(t1))
    + IF (DAY(t2) >= DAY(t1), 0, -1)
FROM 
    (SELECT TIMESTAMP("2010-12-01") as t1, TIMESTAMP("2011-01-01") as t2), // 1
    (SELECT TIMESTAMP("2010-12-02") as t1, TIMESTAMP("2011-01-01") as t2), // 0
    (SELECT TIMESTAMP("2010-12-01") as t1, TIMESTAMP("2011-12-01") as t2), // 12
    (SELECT TIMESTAMP("2010-10-21") as t1, TIMESTAMP("2015-01-10") as t2)  // 50
```

Comment: Thanks Jordan. That works but what I was actually looking for was if the second values falls in a different month it should be calculated based on months apart.

eg. (SELECT TIMESTAMP("2010-12-02") as t1, TIMESTAMP("2011-01-01") as t2) should return 1 as its in the following month

Comment: In that case, you can just remove the `+ IF(DAY...)` clause, and if the timestamps are in different months it will report the difference.

Answer (score 6):

With Standard SQL you can use `date_diff`:

```
#StandardSQL
select date_diff(current_date, date '2018-03-06', month)
```

Comment: This triggers an error:
    `code`DATE_DIFF does not support the MONTH date part at [n:m]`code`
Which is curious because it is not mentioned in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#date_diff)

Comment: For anyone else getting @academy- 's error, you may have used timestamps in the date_diff rather than dates

Comment: Yes! for timestamps, use [timestamp_diff](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#timestamp_diff)

Answer (score 5):

With standard SQL date_diff could work, but if you get an error saying "DATE_DIFF does not support the MONTH date part at [n:m]code", that's because your it's timestamp rather than date. To solve this issue, first cast the timestamp to date, then use date_diff function.
For example:

```
DATE_DIFF(CAST(OrderDate AS DATE), CAST(FirstOrderDate AS DATE), month) AS DATE_DIF
```